# AWS Load balancer listener disappears after adding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-alb

I am not an expert on AWS, but trying to do a simple thing like creating an Application load balancer, adding target groups to it and trying to add a listener. What happens next is what befuddles me. When on the AWS console -> EC2 -> Load balancer -> Listener -> Add Listener page, i select Http:80, under default actions i add 'forward to', chose my instance from drop down, click the 'check' button, which shows the rule added under Default actions. then i click the second save button on the screen, refresh/go-back and there you go -> My listener just disappears. Did someone face this issue before?
I checked out this question: [AWS classic load balancer listener isn't created, then disapears.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226019/aws-classic-load-balancer-listener-isnt-created-then-disapears) - solution din't work for me (i am already pressing second save, which is at the top of the screen, not bottom for ALB).
Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

On the load balancer configuration page, once you add a listener, scroll all the way down and click on "Apply". Happened to me too because I forgot to click the Apply button.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. The big green "Pending" pill that appears after creating the listener is super misleading.